# Fire a tracking Pixel onClick

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have this tracking pixel that would usually be placed in the body of a "installed successfully" page:

```
<img src="http://domain.com/adclick.php" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
```

But instead, I'd like it to fire when someone clicks a download button.  Is this possible? I’m thinking the download button could call a javascript function onClick that would hit the adclick.php page?

Thanks
James

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
<script>
  function fire() {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("src", "http://domain.com/adclick.php");
    /* set other attributes here */
    document.body.appendChild(img);
  }
</script>
<button onClick="fire();">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't much of a PHP question, but at least you're tagging.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function iteration() { 
$.get("http://domain.com/adclick.php");
return false;
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="Tracking Text" onclick="iteration();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, if you are using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadButtonClicked() {
    $('<img src="http://example.com/adclick.php" width="1" height="1" border="0" />').appendTo('body');
}
</script>
<a href="/download" onclick="downloadButtonClicked();">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create an image with

```
var trackingPxl = new Image();
```

and inside your download function set the src

```
trackingPxl.src = 'http://example.com/adclick.php';
```